# Can the line dash of a segment plot be defined by source data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Can the `line_dash` parameter of a segment plot depend on the source data?

```
data = {}
data["dash"] = ["dashed","dashed","solid"]
data["x0"] = [0,1,2]
data["x1"] = [5,6,8]
data["y0"] = [1,1,1]
data["y1"] = [2,1,2]
source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data)
plot.segment(x0="x0", y0="y0", x1="x1", y1="y1", line_dash="dash", source=source)
```

Returns

> ValueError: expected an element of either Enum('solid',
>   'dashed', 'dotted', 'dotdash', 'dashdot'),
>   Regex('^(\d+(\s+\d+)*)?$') or Seq(Int), got 'dash'

Can the `line_dash` property be only set to one value? How do I know which parameters can be set "locally" and which have to be set "globally"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `line_dash` property is not currently "vectorizable" in the way that many other properties (e.g. color, alpha, position, etc.) are. You can look in the Reference Guide for [`Segment.line_dash`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/segment.html#bokeh.models.glyphs.Segment.line_dash) and see that its property type is `DashPattern`. All the properties that are vectorizable will have "Spec" in the type name, e.g [`Segment.line_alpha`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/segment.html#bokeh.models.glyphs.Segment.line_alpha) has a property type `NumberSpec`, so that indicates that you can set the alpha value to either one number, or it can refer to a list of numbers in a ColumnDataSource to vectorize different alphas.

It's possible this situation could be change, there has just never been any evident demand for it, so it was not prioritized. Feel free to make a [Github feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss further.