# How to use a CDS column to set the "line_dash" of a Multiline glyph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I am plotting Multilines with the method `multi_line`.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        x=[3, 3],
        y=[4, 4],
        xs1=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],
        ys1=[[6, 7, 2], [4, 5, 7]],
        xs2=[[8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
        ys2=[[6, 7], [7, 8, 9]],        
        color=['red', 'green'],
        width=[5, 1],
        dash=['solid', 'dashed']
    )
)

p = figure(
    plot_width=400, 
    plot_height=400,
    tools='lasso_select,pan,wheel_zoom'
)

p.multi_line(
    xs='xs1',
    ys='ys1',
    source=source,
    color='color',
    line_join='round',
    line_width='width',    # this is working with the column name, despite the documentatio say nothing
    # line_dash='dash'     # this is not working
)

show(p)
```

A column for `color`, `alpha` or `line_width` can be set on multilines source CDS in order to plot each line in a different way. But this cannot be applied to the `line_dash` attribute. I would like to make the main line `solid` and the rest `dashed`.

If I use the glyph `line` for this main lines then I will lose performance because I need to update more than one glyph at the same time on each plots.

On the other hand I think there are something missing in the documentation about [`line_width`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.multi_line) because a CDS column can be assigned to this method argument and it works:

```
alpha (float) – an alias to set all alpha keyword args at once
color (Color) – an alias to set all color keyword args at once
>> line_width (float) - should this be added because it works with CDS columns?
```

Is there a way to assign a column for the `line_dash` attribute?

I didn´t test the rest of attributes in depth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the line dash of a segment plot be defined by source data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527488/can-the-line-dash-of-a-segment-plot-be-defined-by-source-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are asking in relation to `MultiLine`, this has the same answer as [Can the line dash of a segment plot be defined by source data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527488/can-the-line-dash-of-a-segment-plot-be-defined-by-source-data/50532371#50532371) which is that "vectorizing" the `line_dash` property is not currently supported (as of `0.12.16`) If you want to have different line dashes for now you will have to make separate calls to `line`.