# Python Bokeh multi_line plot with different line_dash

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to add some hover labels and different styling using the Bokeh multi_line function as demonstrated in the following code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
import bokeh.plotting as bpl
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

output_notebook()

fig = bpl.figure(width=500, height=500, match_aspect=True)

multi_line_source = ColumnDataSource({
    'xs': [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
    'ys': [[0, 1, 3, 5], [0, -1, -2, -1]],
    'color': ["red", "green"],
    'line_width': [1, 2],
    'type': ["upper curve", "lower curve"],
    #'line_dash': ["solid", "dashed"]
})

lines = fig.multi_line('xs', 'ys', color='color', line_width='line_width',\
                       #line_dash='line_dash',\
                       source=multi_line_source)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("type", "@type"),
    ],
    renderers=[lines]
)

fig.add_tools(hover)

show(fig)
```

Now, if I also want to add different line dash styles (by removing the two comments in the code above), it doesn't work. As far as I understand, this kind of styling is not supported by Bokeh, and so I wonder how I can achieve this (for example, using the line function)?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a CDS column to set the "line\_dash" of a Multiline glyph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601505/how-to-use-a-cds-column-to-set-the-line-dash-of-a-multiline-glyph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution. I added line_alpha=0 to the multi_line function call,i.e.,

```
lines = fig.multi_line('xs', 'ys', color='color', line_width='line_width',\
                       #line_dash='line_dash',\
                       line_alpha=0,
                       source=multi_line_source)
```

This makes the two lines invisible. Then, I added the two lines with their respective dash style:

```
fig.line([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 5], color="red", line_width=1, line_dash="solid")
fig.line([0, 1, 3, 5], [0, -1, -2, -1], color="green", line_width=2, line_dash="dashed")
```